# Помогите подобрать наиболее точное слово

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, интернет

Не могу найти нужного слова, нужна помощь.
Каким прилагательным можно охарактеризовать пост (запись) в интернет-сообществе, набирающий немного больше отзывов, отметок "Мне нравится" и репостов, чем обычный, но не из-за лучшего содержания, а за счет лучшего времени публикации?
Из рассматриваемых мною вариантов были: эффективный, успешный, резонансный, горячий. Очевидно, что ни одно из этих слов, к сожалению, не подходит.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Своевременный.

Только прилагательное или сочетание тоже можно?

Выгодный по времени пост, вовремя размещённый пост,

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такие определения:
**хитробыстрый, хитроскорый, быстромудрый** (просматриваю аналогию с *хитромудрый*);
**провористый** (разг. синоним к *проворный*);
**проворнистый** (*собственное* словцо — усредненное между *проворный + напористый*; частенько использую — работаю *рядом* с детьми).

P. S. Быстромудрый — от А. Солженицына:
*Под ногами любая наука стлалась,

Быстромудрые бесы вселились, казалось,

В грудь мою...*

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое несколько устаревшее слово - **[благовременный](https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-slovo/1079574.html)**.

> **БЛАГОВРЕМЕННЫЙ**
>       *прил. устар.*
>       Происходящий, появляющийся в нужное, соответствующее время; своевременный.

Мне кажется, здесь оно подходит больше, чем другие.

Answer (score 0):

**Возможные варианты слов**: своевременный, актуальный, насущный, злободневный, также: модный, популярный.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно показать: (1) пост успешный, (2) почему он успешный (из-за времени размещения). 
Самое короткое: *своевременный* (Jasmin), но тут нет попадания в десятку: своевременным пост может быть в более широком смысле слова (актуальный для наших дней), да и успешность тут выражена неявно. Придется быть многословным, например: *успешный благодаря лучшему времени публикации*.